# Error 302 cuando redirecciono un formulario a un archivo php

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario a un documento en php, pero resulta que cuando le doy en el botón de enviar me aparece el error 302, revisando me doy cuenta que el error solo aparece cuando uso la sentencia header, pero cuando comento esta abre el archivo sin problema y me muestra el código 200, tengo entendido que este error puede aparecer por hacer impresiones antes del header, pero no estoy haciendo ninguna ni en el archivo de la conexión y ni en el de registrar.

Les comparto los codigo que uso.

este es el codigo que uso para la conexión.

```html
<?php
 //Conexión
 $server = 'localhost';
 $username = 'localhost';
 $password = '12345678';
 $database = 'mibase';
 $db = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
 
 mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 
 
 //Iniciar la sessión
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
 }
?>
```

Formulario que envio a registrar.php

```html
<?php 
 require_once 'actions/redireccion.php';
 require_once 'includes/header.php';
 require_once'includes/aside.php';
?>

<!--CAJA PRINCIPAL -->
<div id="principal">
 <h1> Crear estudiante</h1>
 <!-- Mostrar errores -->
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['completado'])): ?>
  <div class="alerta alerta-exito">
   <?=$_SESSION['completado']?>
  </div>
 <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['errores']['general'])): ?>
  <div class="alerta alerta-error">
   <?=$_SESSION['errores']['general']?>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <form action="actions/registrar.php" method="POST">
  <label for="nombre">Nombres</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" />
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'nombre') : ''; ?>
   
  <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
  <input type="text" name="apellido"/>
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'apellido') : ''; ?>
  
  <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
  <input type="text" name="telefono"/>
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'telefono') : ''; ?>
  
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'email') : ''; ?> 
  
  <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
  <input type="password" name="contraseña"/>
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'pass') : ''; ?> 
  
  <label for="curso">Curso</label>
  <select name="curso" id="curso1" class="selet">
   <option value="0">Escoja el curso</option>
   <?php 
    $datos = conseguirCursos($db);
    if(!empty($datos)):
     while($dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)):
     ?> 
      <option value="<?=$dato['codigo_curso']?>">
       <?=$dato['descripcion']?>
      </option>
   
     <?php
     endwhile;
    endif;
   ?>
  </select>
  <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'curso') : ''; ?> 
  <div id="profesor"><br/></div>  
  
  <input type="submit"  value="Registrar estudiante" id="margintop"/>
 </form>
 <?php borrarError(); ?>
</div> <!--fin principal-->

<?php require_once "includes/footer.php";?>
```

Y este es el codigo que lo recibe:

```html
<?php
 require_once "conexion.php";
 
 header('Location: ../crear_estudiantes.php');
?>
```

Se supone que cuando llegue acá debe retornar a mi formulario, pero me sale el error 302.

Aca les dejo unas capturas de lo que les digo:

Esta imagen es cuando envio el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como les comente me aparece el error 302 cuando envio los datos de mi formulario a registrar.php.
Y esta imagen es cuando  comento el header

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver aca si me aparece el código 200

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Al parecer no es un código de error, es un 'estado de redirección', https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302 y a lo mejor se debe a que la ruta que pusiste (la url) no es adecuada para la redirección, pero al parecer no es un error, es solo un estado, y el código 200 pues no hace falta decir que es cuando las cosas van completamente bien...

Comment: @Riven, gracias, por tu respuesta, eso mismo leí, pero por que si funciona bien el archivo cuando comento el header o no hace nada cuando está activo???

Comment: De hecho no me hagas caso, el estado 302 significa que si encontró el recurso ósea que efectivamente tu recurso esta bien y tu ruta es correcta, tu archivo no hace nada  cuando comentas el header?, y dime cual es el comportamiento que deseas (para darme una idea), porque realmente despues del header no expones ningún código, que es lo que se supone debería hacer ese código cuando comentas el header??

Comment: Ahhh entiendo, que raro porque te aparecerá en blanco...

Comment: @Riven, se supone que esto me debe insertar la info en la base, pero antes de hacer eso me debe mostrar los errores que puedan haber por no llenar completamente el formulario y eso es lo que no hace

Comment: Puede ser que la SESSION haya expirado en tal momento??, tal vez no muestra los errores debido a que no hay una SESSION que contenga esa información aun o ya expiro... puedes intentar mirar que hay en session al momento de mirar los errores imprimiendolos en alguna parte por el momento (de prueba), para ver si efectivamente siquiera hay una session...

Comment: @Riven te vas a reir cuando te diga por que no mostraba los errores, ya que el if lo tenia asi: if(count($errores){}, claro nunca iba a entrar, tenia que ponerlo if(count($errores) == 0){}

Comment: Bueno, por lo menos se soluciono el problema :3, si a vecez uno pasa por alto detalles muy minimos pero vitales jajajaja.